# Pandas Dataframe object types fillna exception over different datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with different dtypes for the different columns.   E.g.  df.dtypes returns the following.

```
Date                    datetime64[ns]
FundID                           int64
FundName                        object
CumPos                           int64
MTMPrice                       float64
PricingMechanism                object
```

Various of cheese columns have missing values in them.  Doing a group operations on it with NaN values in place cause problems.  To get rid of them with the .fillna() method is the obvious choice. Problem is the obvious clouse for strings are .fillna("")  while  .fillna(0) is the correct choice for ints and floats.   Using either method on DataFrame throws exception.   Any elegant solutions besides doing them individually (have about 30 columns)?   I have a lot of code depending on the DataFrame and would prefer not to retype the columns as it is likely to break some other logic.
Can do:

```
df.FundID.fillna(0)
df.FundName.fillna("")
etc
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can iterate through them and use an `if` statement!

```
for col in df:
    #get dtype for column
    dt = df[col].dtype 
    #check if it is a number
    if dt == int or dt == float:
        df[col].fillna(0)
    else:
        df[col].fillna("")
```

When you iterate through a pandas DataFrame, you will get the names of each of the columns, so to access those columns, you use `df[col]`. This way you don't need to do it manually and the script can just go through each column and check its dtype!

Comment: you need ``inplace=True`` for this to work (or assign the column)

Comment: I agree, that if you not add `inplace=True`, changes won't be saved on the original data frame

Answer (score 6):

You can grab the float64 and object columns using:

```
In [11]: float_cols = df.blocks['float64'].columns

In [12]: object_cols = df.blocks['object'].columns
```

*and int columns won't have NaNs else they [would be upcast to float](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).*

Now you can apply the respective [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)s, one cheeky way:

```
In [13]: d1 = dict((col, '') for col in object_cols)

In [14]: d2 = dict((col, 0) for col in float_cols)

In [15]: df.fillna(value=dict(d1, **d2))
```

Comment: Note: although this `dict(d1, **d2)` is a neat trick there is some debate whether it is a actually "valid" syntax :)

Comment: see df.blocks is new pandas 0.11.0 method

Comment: @Joop worth upgrading and not just for blocks! :)

Answer (score 4):

similar to @Guddi: A bit verbose, but still more concise then @Ryan's answer and keeping all columns:

```
df[df.select_dtypes("object").columns] = df.select_dtypes("object").fillna("")
```

Comment: I liked this one.  My answer nearly duplicate, except I avoid running `df.select_dtypes` twice.

Answer (score 2):

A compact version example:

```
#replace Nan with '' for columns of type 'object'
df=df.select_dtypes(include='object').fillna('')
```

However, after the above operation, the dataframe will only contain the 'object' type columns. For keeping all columns, use the solution proposed by @Ryan Saxe.

Comment: What if the `object`s aren't meant to be strings (if that can even happen)?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than running the conversion one column at a time, which is *inefficient*, here is a way to grab all of the int or float columns and change in one shot.

```
int_float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']).columns
df[int_float_cols] = df[int_float_cols].fillna(value=0)
```

Obvious how to adapt this to handle object.

I'm aware that in Pandas older versions, there were no NAs allowed in integers, so grabbing the "ints" is not strictly necessary and it may accidentially promote ints to floats. However, in our use case, it is better to be safe than sorry.

I ran into this because ordinary approach, `df.fillna(0)` corrupted all of the datetime variables.

Comment: @nik's answer nearly same.  Both are much more desirable than changing one column at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan Saxe's answer is accurate. To get it to work on my data I had to set `inplace=True` and also `data= 0` and `data= ""`. See code below:

```
for col in df:
    #get dtype for column
    dt = df[col].dtype 
    #check if it is a number
    if dt == int or dt == float:
        df[col].fillna(data=0, inplace=True)
    else:
        df[col].fillna(data="", inplace=True)
```

Comment: inplace is not necessary.  inplace is discouraged by experts lately, write `df[col] = df[col].fillna(0)` instead if you want to do this one col at a time.

Comment: Why is `inplace` discouraged (reference to "experts"?)?